# Validate pre-defined tags in PHP

Tags: php

I have a feature to allow user to build message with pre-defined tags.

These are the ONLY tags I'm currently allow user to input, so in PHP it should validate if the tags are one of these.

What is the best way and how to perform validation? Using preg_match?

[image]

Comment: What type of validation do you want to perform ? and please share the code you tried ?

Comment: Do you mean that customers should not be allowed to include literal brackets in their messages?

Comment: The purpose of validation is to prevent other pattern e.g. {books} which is obviously not allowed in the list

Comment: Extract all tags, e.g. with a regex `/\{\w+\}/`, then iterate through all found tags and confirm that they're in a list of whitelisted tags.

Answer (score -1):

```
function findTag($str,$replaceTag = []){
    if(!$str){
        return false;
    }
    $end = strlen($str);
    $i=0;
    while($i<=$end){
        if(!isset($str[$i])){
            break;
        }
        //Find tag
        if($str[$i]=='{'){
            $tag = '';
            for($j=$i+1;$j<=$end;$j++){
                if($str[$j]=='}'){
                    break;
                }
                //Check nested tag {xyz{abc}efg}
                if($str[$j]=='{'){
                    return -1;//use nested tag
                }
                $tag.=$str[$j];
            }
            if(!isset($replaceTag[$tag])){
                return -2;//invalid tag you can skip or prevent string parsing
            }
            //Replace tag with value
            $str = substr_replace($str,$replaceTag[$tag],$i,$j);
            $i=$j;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $str;
}

$str = 'Customer name : {tag1}, thank you for your {tag{tag2}}';
$replaceTag = ['tag1'=>' tag 1 value'];
var_dump(findTag($str,$replaceTag));
```